# How to sign in with apple logout

Tags: ios, swift

When using Apple login, I want to know how to log out. Two revoking methods I know

[1] Upon opening your app

1. Open the Settings app, then tap [your name].
2. Tap Password & Security
3. Tap Apps Using Your Apple ID.

```
let authorizationAppleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()

  authorizationAppleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: "currentUserIdentifier") { (credentialState: ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider.CredentialState, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
      print(error)
      // Something went wrong check error state
      return
    }
    switch (credentialState) {
    case .authorized:
      //User is authorized to continue using your app
      break
    case .revoked:
      //User has revoked access to your app
      break
    case .notFound:
      //User is not found, meaning that the user never signed in through Apple ID
      break
    default: break
    }
  }
```

How to know through this code when running the app afterwards

[2] While your app is running

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
  let sessionNotificationName = NSNotification.Name.ASAuthorizationAppleIDProviderCredentialRevoked

  appleIDSessionObserver = notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: sessionNotificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification: Notification) in
    //Sign user out
  }
```

This code notifies when a credentialState becomes revoked when a user session changes.

What I'm curious about is [2] While your app is running, in what situation is the user session revoked in the app? For example, if you press the logout button, credentialState becomes revoked, you will receive notifications and execute the logout function, right? How to revoked appleId CredentialState in the context of using the app?

Comment: The user wouldn't typically go in to settings to logout; that actually removes the association between your app and their Apple ID. When they come back to your app they would potentially be seen as a new user on your side. If you want to provide a logout function in your app you just throw away the token that you have